# Email before start

Tags: new-job, email

I'll soon be starting at a big consulting firm. The new analysts started mid July but because I am on an H1b visa I'll be starting mid October.

A friend, who is working there, told me she heard no one at the office really knows when I am supposed to be joining the firm, especially since every new analyst started a couple months ago. She mentioned two principals, which is what worries me.

While its true that I've been communicating throughout the summer mainly with HR and with their immigration office I find it strange that HR wouldn't talk to anyone in charge of the department. I'm pretty new to this so I am not sure if this is normal or not.

My question is: Should I send an email mentioning my start date to a Managing Director or someone of that sort with whom I worked closely during my internship last summer? If so, any ideas how to start it or phrase it?

Comment: Do you have an offer letter or contract with a start date?

Comment: @Mister Positive I have an offer letter with salary, benefits, etc but no start date on it. The start date was communicated to me via email by HR.

Comment: @Mister Positive the company is very big, one of the big 3 consulting firms. Could it be that maybe HR and the dept don't communicate thoroughly? I have 2 weeks before I start, would sending an email to one of my bosses saying I look forward to starting, if there's anything I should hand in before starting, and politely mentioning when I'll be starting a bad idea? I'm not sure what's the usual etiquette for this and definitely don't want to bother them.

Comment: @JJames Please do not deface your post. If you would like to delete your question or have it disassociated from your account, you can flag your post and request that a moderator do so.

Answer (score 2):

You have an offer letter and an email from the HR department with a start date. Since you have been communicating with HR about your status, you should expect that everything is fine.

I wouldn't send an email to a manager unless HR tells you it's ok to do so. Up until your first day, your expected assignment may change many times, so you may not know who to send the email to. Also, as you say it's a very large consulting firm, they are sure to have processes in place between HR and management for notifying them of incoming employees.

You should not interpret your friend's comments as anything negative. It is very common for people to be busy with the work they have at hand and to not spend time thinking about a future employee until the date of their arrival is very near. Even then, it is quite common for a new employee to be a surprise to their manager on their first day. It happens. People are busy and time gets away from them. Don't take it personally.

Unless your friend is in management, she likely has no idea about everything management is talking about and making plans for. So when she says nobody is talking about you, it's most likely a simple matter of nobody having anything to say about you because you don't work there, yet, and they're busy doing their jobs.

Just stay in touch with HR and show up at the appointed time on your first day. Everything else will be fine. Congratulations on the new job and good luck!

Answer (score -1):

If this supposed uncertainty really bothers you, you may want to write an email to your future manager with some innocent questions **mentioning your start date**.

You may want to ask what time you should report on your first day, or where to. Depending on your exact circumstances pick an appropriate one.